Every $\mathbb{R}P^n$, $n>1$, is a preimage of some regular value of some smooth map $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$
I am trying to prove or disprove two statements:

Every $\mathbb{R}P^n$, $n>1$, is a preimage of some regular value of some smooth map $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$

and

There is no $n>1$ such that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ would be a preimage of some regular value of some smooth map $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$

Some observations:
If every $\mathbb{R}P^n$, $n>1$, is a preimage of some regular value of some smooth map $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ then we get canonical choice of trivialization of the normal bundle $\nu\mathbb{R}P^n$. And that is iff there exists framed submanifold manifold $W\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ such that $\partial W=\mathbb{R}P^n\cup N'$ and $N'\subset\partial\mathbb{R}^{m+n}=\emptyset$.
The normal bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is trivial for every $n$.
Not all Stiefel-Whitney numbers of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ are zero so there does not exist manifold $W$ such that $\partial W=\mathbb{R}P^n$.
Does Pontrjagin-Thom construction yield any help?

"Not all Stiefel-Whitney numbers of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ are zero [...]" that's only true iff $n$ is even.

In any case, think about what "$\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ has non-trivial SW-classes" implies for the normal bundle in any embedding into $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Both statements are false.
Let's start with the second one, because it's easier: $\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}}\RP^3$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$ which is a Lie group and therefore parallelizable, so the normal bundle in embeddings of sufficiently high codimension into $\mathbb{R}^N$ is trivial, whence $SO(3)$ is the level set of some function (alternatively, you can of course write down a defining function explicitly).
For the first question, let me first of all point out that "not all SW-numbers of $\RP^n$ are zero" is false: In fact the SW-numbers of $\RP^n$ vanish if and only if $n$ is odd. It suffices, however, to find a single $n$ for which these numbers do not vanish; in fact, a single $n$ for which some SW-class in positive degree doesn't vanish is enough: As you note, if $\RP^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n + m}$ is a regular level set, then its normal bundle must be trivial, but
$$
   1 \neq \omega(T\RP^n) = \omega(T\RP^n \oplus \nu \RP^n) \cong \omega(T\mathbb{R}^{n + m}|_{\RP^n}) = 1
$$
which is absurd (here $\omega$ denotes the total SW-class).

In fact, it's not hard to see that $\omega(T\RP^n) = 1$ iff $n + 1$ is a power of 2, so the only regular level set candidates are $\RP^1$, $\RP^3$, $\RP^7$, $\RP^{15}$, and so forth. Of these, one can show that only $\RP^1$, $\RP^3$, and $\RP^7$ are parallelizable and therefore regular level sets, although it may still be the case that some (or all) $\RP^{2^k - 1}$ are regular level sets.
